# mod_rewrite - How to keep rewritten addresses without changing html links

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's say I have a website with given sites:
index.php
info.php

In order to hide the "index.php" part of the URL and to change "info.php" to "info" I create the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^info$ info.php
RewriteRule ^.$ index.php
```

It works just fine when I type the new URLs directly into address bar, but inside index.php I have the:

```
<a href="info.php">
```

and so when I click the link, it directs me to the info page and displays "info.php" in the URL. If I want to see just "info" in the URL after clicking the link, do I have to change the links inside HTML code? Or is there a way to make .htaccess file do it automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file for changing these links automatically:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

**But it is highly recommended to change these links in your HTML page to avoid one external redirect.**